# Stop connecting to a server after n unsuccessful attempts

Tags: python, error-handling

1. I am trying to connect to a server.
2. If the connection goes through, then print an apt message.
3. If the connection does not go through, try for a total of n times. And quit after the nth attempt with an apt message.

I set up a mock server like this -

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_status = random.choice([True, False, False, False])

    def get_connection(self):
        if self.connection_status:
            return "Connected"
        else:
            raise EnvironmentError("Connection Error")
```

And then I tested it as follows -

```
def connect_to_server():
    s = Server()
    try:
        return s.get_connection()
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        return str(e)

def main():
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        connection = connect_to_server()
        if connection == "Connection Error":
            count += 1
            print(connection, count)
            if count == 3:
                print("No more connection attempts")
        else:
            count = 0
            print(connection)
```

So, after 3 re-connection attempts, the program will terminate.

Is there a better / elegant way to do this?

Comment: Assuming that you intended to return dummy data rather than a status string, instead of `return "Connected"`, may I suggest `return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"`? Better yet, wrap it in a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

Comment: You might want to check [retrying](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying), which provides a decorator for just that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The smart and polite thing to do when retrying is to wait some random (and possibly increasing) interval between retries.  The last thing you want to do to a failing server or network is to overwhelm it with connections as fast as the clients are able to generate them.

In `connect_to_server()`, squashing the `EnvironmentError` into a string is a bad idea.  Just letting the exception propagate would better convey the fact that a failure occurred.  Besides, what if the server really wanted to send the string `"Connection Error"` as its message?  Changing the client's behaviour based on the payload might even be considered a mild denial-of-service vulnerability.

The idiomatic way to write a counting loop in Python is to use `range()`.

Defining a `retry()` function would be worthwhile for three reasons:

- It makes your code self-documenting
- It declutters your `main()`
- You might be able to reuse the retry logic if it's needed elsewhere

One solution is to define a `@retry` decorator for functions:

```
from functools import wraps
from random import random
from time import sleep

def retry(max_tries=3, max_retry_interval=2, exceptions=[Exception],
          failure_callback=lambda exc, attempt, max_tries: None):
    """Tries calling the decorated function up to max_tries times until
    it succeeds, and returns its result.

    Any exceptions of the specified types thrown by the decorated function
    will trigger a retry.  The failure_callback is called with each failure,
    with the exception, the attempt number (starting with 0), and max_tries
    max_tries as callback parameters.

    There is a random delay of up to max_retry_interval seconds between
    tries.

    If max_tries attempts all result in failure, then the last encountered
    exception is raised. """
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwds):
            exception = None
            for attempt in range(max_tries):
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwds)
                except Exception as e:
                    if not next((e for cls in exceptions if isinstance(e, cls)), None):
                        # Unexpected type of exception
                        raise 
                    failure_callback(e, attempt, max_tries)
                    exception = e
                    if attempt < max_tries - 1:
                        sleep(max_retry_interval * random())
            if exception is not None:
                raise exception
        return retry_wrapper
    return decorator
```

Then your code would look like:

```
@retry(3, 5, [EnvironmentError], lambda exc, attempt, max_tries: print("Connection Error"))
def connect_to_server():
    …

def main():
    try:
        connection = connect_to_server()
        print(connection)
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        print(e)
        print("No more connection attempts")
```

Or, without hard-coding the retry parameters in a decorator:

```
def connect_to_server():
    …

def main():
    try:
        retry3times = retry(3, 5, [EnvironmentError],
                            lambda _, _, _: print("Connection Error"))
        connection = (retry3times(connect_to_server))()
        print(connection)
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        print(e)
        print("No more connection attempts")
```

Comment: Looks like this functions can also be used a decorator.

Comment: @200_success  
**The smart and polite thing to do when retrying is to wait some random (and possibly increasing) interval between retries.**  

Agreed, and that is how I would implement it eventually. Planning to do powers of 2 intervals.  

**I'll fill in retry() when I have more time.**  

Don't, unless you really want to. I only needed a code review. With your answer, I can do the implementation.